# How to turn off mousewheel touching on Ipad in Flexslider

Tags: ipad, flexslider

I am using Flexslider and on ipad it is not userfriendly with mousewheel effect because when user reached to this slider part it is difficult to go ahead to bottom.I want to diable it generally.I tried Flexslider option.Here it is, but it is not working 
`$('.promotions-slider').flexslider({
        animation : 'slide',
        slideshow : false,
        prevText: "",
        nextText: "",
        slideshowSpeed: 2000,
        mousewheel: false, 
        animationSpeed: 600,
        controlNav : false,
        minItems: 1,
        maxItems: 1
    });`
Help me please to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah finally I found a solution.Flexslider had another two optiones **touch and useCss**.My final code is

```
$('.promotions-slider').flexslider({
    animation : 'slide',
    slideshow : false,
    prevText: "",
    nextText: "",
    slideshowSpeed: 2000,
    mousewheel: false, 
    animationSpeed: 600,
    touch: false,
    useCSS: false,
    controlNav : false,
    minItems: 1,
    maxItems: 1
});
```

Now it is working 100%.